# How to get root url with subdirectories

Tags: javascript, angular, iis

I want to get the full root route url of my application when it's hosted in multiple subdirectories.
Whenever I retrieve an url I get only the hostname and port or when I try something like window.location.href I alos get queryparams and routes in the url which I don't want.

for example: if my app is hosted on : http://hostname/subdir1/subdir2/myapp
I want to get the  http://hostname/subdir1/subdir2/ part from it, regardless of current router state

Answer (score 2):

You can use pop() and URL API for this:

```js
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
let path = url.pathname.split("/");
path.pop();
url.pathname = path.join("/")
console.log(url.href)
```

Comment: Yes but then I'll have to be in a root route to get this href, because when I am in a different routing state the href will contain params. I'm looking for a solution that I can get the url anywhere without params or routes in it.